# XtraGrid Master-Detail in separate grid

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use xtragrids with entity framework. I have 2 sql tables. I show in gridControl1 the partners table and in gridControl2 the partner_contacts table. How can How can I make relation between gridControl1 to gridControl2. If I click a row in gridControl1 i want to show related rows in gridControl2.

1st table: partners
- partnerId
- partnerName

2nd table: partner_contacts
- partner_contactsId
- partner_contactsName
- partner_contacts_partner_FK

```
public partial class frmPartnersList : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    ValinorEntities valinor = new ValinorEntities();

    public frmPartnersList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        gridControl1.DataSource = valinor.partners;
        gridControl2.DataSource = valinor.partner_contacts;
    }
 }
```

---

I tried this:

```
        object obj = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0], gridView1.FocusedColumn.FieldName);

        string obj2 = obj.ToString();

        var selectedPartner = valinor.partners.Where(p => p.partnerId = obj2).FirstOrDefault();
        if (selectedPartner != null)
            gridControl2.DataSource = selectedPartner.partner_contacts;
```

I had 2 errors:

- Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
- Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'
- Delegate 'System.Func' does not take 1 arguments

for this code:(p => p.partnerId = obj2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FocusedRowChanged` event in gridcontrol1.

For example when focused row changed in gridcontrol1

```
int partnerId=(int)gridview1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("PartnerID");

gridcontrol2.DataSource=valinor.partner_contacts.where(partner_contact=>partner_contact.PartnerId=partnerId);
```

or if you have relationship added in partner entity in your entity model, then

```
var selectedPartner=valinor.partners.where(p=>p.PartnerId=partnerId).FirstOrDefault();
if(selectedPartner!=null)
gridcontrol2.datasource=selectedPartner.Contacts;
```

I assumed relationship names... It may differ on your model.